# Plotting iteratively defined function in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, graph, plot, fractals

I'm not a MATLAB professional and so, I need some help at producing a 3D plot of the iteratively defined function **f** : **R^2-0** -> **R** defined below (in pseudocode) for **x,y** values in **[-1,1]** and

For each **I = 1,2,3** and **A = (0.5,0.5)**

```
function  f(v in R^2-0)
{
    a=b=0;     (a,b in R)        
    for (i=0; i<I; i=i+1)
    {
        v = |v| / ||v||^2 - A;
        a = a + | ||v||-b |;
        b = ||v||;
    }
    return a;
}
```

(|**v**| denotes component-wise vector absolute value)

(If you want you can look at the fractal that is generated by the function at my question on math-exchange here:

https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1457733/a-question-about-a-fractal-like-iteratively-defined-function
)

MATLAB code to do that will be appreciated.

Much Thanks.

Comment: So is not a coding service. Where do you have problems implementing the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save this your main program:

```
clear
clc
close all

% I = 1;
% A = [ 0.5 0.5 ];

I = 10;
A = [ 0.5 0.5 0.5 ];

xmin = -1;
xmax = 1;

ymin = -1;
ymax = 1;

nx = 101;
ny = 101;

dx = (xmax - xmin) / (nx - 1);
dy = (ymax - ymin) / (ny - 1);

x = xmin: dx: xmax;
y = ymin: dy: ymax;

for ix = 1: nx
    for iy = 1: ny
        if (length(A) == 2)
            z(iy, ix) = f([x(ix) y(iy)], A, I);
        elseif (length(A) == 3)
            z(iy, ix) = f([x(ix) y(iy) 0], A, I);
        end
    end
end

pcolor(x, y, z)
shading interp
```

Then save this function in the same directory as the main program as `f.m`:

```
function result = f(v, A, I)

a = 0;
b = 0;

for i = 1: I
    v = abs(v) / dot(v, v) - A;
    a = a + abs(norm(v) - b);
    b = norm(v);
end
result = a;

end
```